# Why does my function not print my dString variable?

Tags: python

Im trying to write a simpleprogram that tells what day of the week it is depending on the number thats inputted (1-monday, 2-tuesday...etc).However when I run it, its output is "the day is" and doesnt print out dString.

```
    def dayString(dayNum):

        dayString = ""

        if dayString==1:
            print("Monday")
        elif dayString==2:
            print("Tuesday")
        elif dayString==3:
            print("Wednesday")
        elif dayString==4:
            print("Thrusday")
        elif dayString==5:
            print("Friday")
        elif dayString==6:
            print("Saturday")
        elif dayString==7:
            print("Sunday")
        return(dayString)

    def main():
        n = int(input('Enter the number of the day: '))
        dString = dayString(n)
        print('The day is', dString)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: `dayString==1`  Shouldn't you be comparing `dayNum`?  And why are you returning `dayString`?  It will always be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
In [1864]: def dayString(dayNum): 
      ...:         dayString = '' 

      ...:         if dayNum==1: 
      ...:             dayString = "Monday" 
      ...:         elif dayNum==2: 
      ...:             dayString = "Tuesday" 
      ...:         elif dayNum==3: 
      ...:             dayString = "Wednesday" 
      ...:         elif dayNum==4: 
      ...:             dayString ="Thrusday" 
      ...:         elif dayNum==5: 
      ...:             dayString ="Friday" 
      ...:         elif dayNum==6: 
      ...:             dayString ="Saturday" 
      ...:         elif dayNum==7: 
      ...:             dayString ="Sunday" 
      ...:         return(dayString) 
      ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [1865]: dayString(2)                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[1865]: 'Tuesday'
```

Comment: it still gives me the same result when I applied this

Comment: What is the result it is giving? Please copy paste it properly. It should give you the day. I've already attached sample output of my code.

Comment: okay thanks I didnt to it correctly your solution worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change your function:

```
def dayString(dayNum):

    dayStr = ""

    if dayNum==1:
        dayStr="Monday" 
        print("Monday")
     elif idayNum==2:
        dayStr="Tuesday" 
        print("Tuesday")
     elif... 
     return dayStr
```